# laravel paginate deal with on controller or view

Tags: laravel, request, pagination

It's about the paginate function on laravel 5.5
when I use the  $request_all=$request->all() to get huge dat from DB

Which is better to the server loading

1. deal with $request_all on controller 
   then transfer the selected data to the view page
   just like
       `return View('show)
       ->with('name', $request_all['name']);`

2.just send the $request_all to the view page 
  just like
         return View('show)
                ->with('request_all', $request_all);

And when I use the paginate function

```
    public function index()
    {
    $products = DB::table('product')->paginate(15);

    return view('index', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

Is the cache or session   on the server machine or the user machine?

(1)
when user read the page 1 , Are the other page waiting on the server occupied the server's memory?
(2)Or when users post the request ,the all pages send to the user machine's memory at once.

If the data is so huge the the machine will out of the memory?

Comment: please clarify your question..cannot understand.

Comment: do you want to understand paginate function?

Comment: I have two question. One is the server session or the user cache. The other is the working theory of the pagination function

Comment: Does it has different when the data is deal with on the Controller page or  the blade page?

Comment: And the pagination get the data from the DB once, Or many times just like one time when the user change one page, 100 pages means 100 times get the data from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

> Ok so **First** is **Laravel Session**:

A session token is a unique identifier that is generated and sent from a server to a client to identify the current interaction session. The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in **GET** or **POST** queries.
Sessions provide a way to store information about the user across multiple requests.

In Laravel, To **access** the session data,

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key'); //which will take one argument, here “key”
```

To **store** the session data you can use,

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value'); //two arguments
```

To implement session in your project, you can use this laravel documentation [Laravel session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#configuration).

> Second is **Laravel Paginate Fucntion**,

Laravel's paginator is integrated with the **query builder** and **Eloquent ORM** and provides convenient, easy-to-use pagination of database results. 
Function which is used for pagination in laravel is **paginate()** function with model.

```
$users = App\User::paginate(15);
```

This function **retrieves** only **15 items** from database. After that, you have to manage link for **previous** and **next** and other pages with numbers.
In links, you have to pass data of another page number like you are showing **1st page** then you have to give **2nd page number** in **next** button link.
And then if you click on **next** link you will get another **15items** for your page.This is how laravel pagination works.
For more helpful content to implement laravel pagination here is link [Laravel pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#introduction).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? tell me if any query I will try to solve it or it's helpful  just accept my answer @robspin

Comment: Thanks for your reply.! 
1.So there are no difference deal with the data between the Controller page and the blade page?
2.So does the pagination  get all data at once from the DB and store on the server session.(so the data is more the loading is more to the server, buy not for the user's machine though it received one page one link.

Comment: No Laravel pagination get only data defined in **paginate(15)** function like in this 15 data will be taken from the database. And we can pass any value in this function.